# Error on bindValue

Tags: php, forms, bindvalue

I already browsed the Internet, but could not find and understand any solution provided.

Basically, I created (or rather copied some scripts from the Internet) and tried to work on the scripts to make a registration page. I'm using PHP, Mysql  and XAMPP. The connection is fine already.. I tested some data inputs on a basic form etc.

but My problem is, after I messed around with the scripts, I managed to insert data into the table (peekdoordb)...all the hashing and validation form worked..except that, the form keeps submitting data into the DB even when data is wrong or the field is empty. After I messed around again, then the problem arises. The error is on " `$stmt->bindValue(':name', $name);`"

I keep getting this error on browser;

> Notice: Undefined variable: stmt in C:\xampp\htdocs\eventsite\TMP1kjqc3x.php on 
>       line 194

and

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bindValue() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\eventsite\TMP1kjqc3x.php on line 194

The registration.php (registration page) include 2 files which are connect.php and password.php but I never messed anything with those 2 files, because before that, data could be submitted only the problem was with the form, data keeps inserting in DB like I mentioned previously. But the main problem now is about this error.

```
<?php

//register.php

/**
* Start the session.
*/
session_start();

//Include  password_compat library.

require 'lib/password.php';


//Include MySQL connection.

require 'connect.php';


//define variables and define to null.
$nameError = $telnoError = $usernameError = $passwordError ="";
$name = $telno = $username = $pass = "";


//Retrieve the field values from registration form.
$name = !empty($_POST ['name']) ? trim($_POST['name']) : null ;
$telno = !empty ($_POST ['telno']) ? trim($_POST['telno']) : null;
$username = !empty($_POST['username']) ? trim($_POST['username']) : null;
$pass = !empty($_POST['password']) ? trim($_POST['password']) : null;

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}   

$formValid = true; // Boolean - Set to true b4 validating  

//If the POST var "register" exists ( the submit button), then I can
//assume that the user has submitted the registration form.
if(isset($_POST['register'])){


//TO ADD: Error checking (username characters, password length, etc).
//Basically, you will need to add your own error checking BEFORE
//the prepared statement is built and executed.

//Now, we need to check if the supplied username already exists.

//Construct the SQL statement and prepare it.

    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $nameError = "Name is required";
    }else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
// check name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
            $nameError = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["telno"])) {
        $telnoError = "Tel number is required";
    } else {
        $telno = test_input($_POST["telno"]);
// check if e-mail address syntax is valid or not
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$telno)) {
            $telnoError = "Invalid tel no format";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
        $usernameError = "username is required";
    } else {
        $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
// check name only contains letters and email syntax
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$username)) {
            $usernameError = "Only letters and email syntax required";
        }
    }


    if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
        $passwordError = "passworde is required";
    } else {
        $pass = test_input($_POST["password"]);
// check name only contains letters and email syntax
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$pass)) {
            $passwordError = "Only password letter syntax";
        }
    }


//*******************************************************************   



    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(username) AS num FROM users WHERE username = :username";

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

//Bind the provided username to our prepared statement.
    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);


//Execute.
    $stmt->execute();

//Fetch the row.
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//If the provided username already exists - display error.
//TO ADD - Your own method of handling this error. For example purposes,
//I'm just going to kill the script completely, as error handling is outside
//the scope of this tutorial.
    if($row['num'] > 0){
        die('That username already exists!');
    }

//Hash the password as we do NOT want to store our passwords in plain text.
    $passwordHash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 12));
}



//If the signup process is successful.
elseif($formValid){


//******************************ppppp       

//Bind our variables.

    $stmt->bindValue(':name', $name);
    $stmt->bindValue(':telno', $telno);
    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
    $stmt->bindValue(':password', $passwordHash);
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql); 


//Prepare our INSERT statement.
//Remember: We are inserting a new row into our users table.
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, telno, username, password) VALUES (:name, :telno, :username, :password)";




//Execute the statement and insert the new account.
    $result = $stmt->execute();





//What you do here is up to you!
    echo 'Thank you for registering with our website.';
}
else {
    die('something wrong!'); 
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Register</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .lucida {
            font-family: "MS Serif", "New York", serif;
        }
        body form table {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
    <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
    <h1 align="center">     Register</h1>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"  method="post">
        <div align="center">
            <table width="800" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td width="404" class="lucida"><div align="right">Name :</div></td>
                    <td width="386"><input class="input" name="name" type="text" value="<?PHP print $name ; ?>">
                        <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameError;?></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="lucida"><div align="right">Contact Number :</div></td>
                        <td><input class="input" name="telno" type="text" value="<?PHP print $telno ; ?>">
                            <span class="error">* <?php echo $telnoError;?></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="lucida"><div align="right">Email (Username) :</div></td>
                            <td><input class="input" name="username" type="text" value="<?PHP print $username ; ?>">
                                <span class="error">* <?php echo $usernameError;?></span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="lucida"><div align="right">Password :</div></td>
                                <td><input class="input" name="password" type="text" value="">
                                    <span class="error">* <?php echo $passwordError;?></span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="lucida"><div align="right"></div></td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><div align="right"></div></td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><div align="right"></div></td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register">
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Hope anyone can help ASAP..I've been working on this single page for more than a week.. it's driving me crazy.....It was more easier when I used dreamweaver in the past.. trying to go through PHP scripts is quite challenging..

Comment: Please use `bindParam` instead of `bindValue`

Comment: Which is the line of error?

Comment: Hi Linda, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please indent your code and leave only the parts that are necessary for the question. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: what's happening here Linda is that you've assigned your binds and preparing before the execute. `$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);` and `$sql = "INSERT INTO users` need to be inversed and the binds after the query. the `$query` variable is being assigned before the query, kind of like placing the wagon before the horse, as it were. @LindaMay

Comment: @Fred-ii- Absolutely right

Comment: @Chinu and *that's* what you needed to write in your answer ;-)

Comment: another thing is that you're using ternary operators and then checking for emptyness in another function with functions you don't really need (most of) and you're using prepared statements. There is no need for all those really. I think you found a few scripts on the web and pieced them together, correct?

Comment: The best place to learn, is from the manual itself http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php - Rewrite your code and try again. You really don't need that `test_input()` function here.

Comment: Updated my answer Can you please check.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this -

```
//Prepare our INSERT statement.
//Remember: We are inserting a new row into our users table.
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, telno, username, password) VALUES (:name, :telno, :username, :password)";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql); 

$stmt->bindValue(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindValue(':telno', $telno);
$stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
$stmt->bindValue(':password', $passwordHash);


//Execute the statement and insert the new account.
$stmt->execute();
```

You have `bindValue` before `prepare` your statement so you are getting this error. Can `prepare` your statement below your `$sql` variable then bind your value. This is working for me.

**UPDATED ANSWER**

```
<?php
//register.php

/**
 * Start the session.
 */
session_start();

//Include  password_compat library.
require 'lib/password.php';
//Include MySQL connection.

require 'connect.php';


//define variables and define to null.
$nameError = $telnoError = $usernameError = $passwordError = "";
$name = $telno = $username = $pass = "";


//Retrieve the field values from registration form.
$name = !empty($_POST ['name']) ? trim($_POST['name']) : null;
$telno = !empty($_POST ['telno']) ? trim($_POST['telno']) : null;
$username = !empty($_POST['username']) ? trim($_POST['username']) : null;
$pass = !empty($_POST['password']) ? trim($_POST['password']) : null;

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

$formValid = true; // Boolean - Set to true b4 validating  
//If the POST var "register" exists ( the submit button), then I can
//assume that the user has submitted the registration form.
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {


//TO ADD: Error checking (username characters, password length, etc).
//Basically, you will need to add your own error checking BEFORE
//the prepared statement is built and executed.
//Now, we need to check if the supplied username already exists.
//Construct the SQL statement and prepare it.

    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $nameError = "Name is required";
        $formValid = false;
    } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
// check name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $name)) {
            $nameError = "Only letters and white space allowed";
            $formValid = false;
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["telno"])) {
        $telnoError = "Tel number is required";
        $formValid = false;
    } else {
        $telno = test_input($_POST["telno"]);
// check if e-mail address syntax is valid or not
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $telno)) {
            $telnoError = "Invalid tel no format";
            $formValid = false;
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
        $usernameError = "username is required";
        $formValid = false;
    } else {
        $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
// check name only contains letters and email syntax
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $username)) {
            $usernameError = "Only letters and email syntax required";
            $formValid = false;
        }
    }


    if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
        $passwordError = "passworde is required";
        $formValid = false;
    } else {
        $pass = test_input($_POST["password"]);
// check name only contains letters and email syntax
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $pass)) {
            $passwordError = "Only password letter syntax";
            $formValid = false;
        }
    }


//*******************************************************************   



    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(username) AS num FROM users WHERE username = :username";

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

//Bind the provided username to our prepared statement.
    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);


//Execute.
    $stmt->execute();

//Fetch the row.
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//If the provided username already exists - display error.
//TO ADD - Your own method of handling this error. For example purposes,
//I'm just going to kill the script completely, as error handling is outside
//the scope of this tutorial.
    if ($row['num'] > 0) {
        $usernameError = 'That username already exists!';
        $formValid = false;
    }

//Hash the password as we do NOT want to store our passwords in plain text.
    $passwordHash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 12));
    //$passwordHash = $pass;

    if ($formValid) {
//******************************ppppp       
//Bind our variables.
//Prepare our INSERT statement.
//Remember: We are inserting a new row into our users table.
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, telno, username, password) VALUES (:name, :telno, :username, :password)";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindValue(':name', $name);
        $stmt->bindValue(':telno', $telno);
        $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
        $stmt->bindValue(':password', $passwordHash);





//Execute the statement and insert the new account.
        $result = $stmt->execute();





//What you do here is up to you!
        echo 'Thank you for registering with our website.';
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Register</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .lucida {
                font-family: "MS Serif", "New York", serif;
            }
            body form table {
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
        <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
        <h1 align="center">     Register</h1>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>"  method="post">
            <div align="center">
                <table width="800" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="404" class="lucida"><div align="right">Name :</div></td>
                        <td width="386"><input class="input" name="name" type="text" value="<?PHP print $name; ?>">
                            <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameError; ?></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="lucida"><div align="right">Contact Number :</div></td>
                        <td><input class="input" name="telno" type="text" value="<?PHP print $telno; ?>">
                            <span class="error">* <?php echo $telnoError; ?></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="lucida"><div align="right">Email (Username) :</div></td>
                        <td><input class="input" name="username" type="text" value="<?PHP print $username; ?>">
                            <span class="error">* <?php echo $usernameError; ?></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="lucida"><div align="right">Password :</div></td>
                        <td><input class="input" name="password" type="text" value="">
                            <span class="error">* <?php echo $passwordError; ?></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="lucida"><div align="right"></div></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><div align="right"></div></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><div align="right"></div></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register">
                <br>
            </div>
        </button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please give an explanation here, so that the OP and visitors to the question know what you  did, so they can "learn" from this. This is a low-quality answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- he is just missed some line so i change the line here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- he is define $sql variable after the prepare statement. How can prepare this?

Comment: HI..I ran the script this morning..it was working perfectly.. wow...again..Thank you again to Chinu, Topher, Fred-ii, rray and to the Founder of stackoverflow...I never expected a massive overhaul on the scripts..

Comment: I studied your answer and noticed my previous scripts contained many errors here and there..I've been working on this single page day and night for  more than a week..I just don't know how you manage to do it in a few minutes..or second..Thank you again..I apologise for troubling all of you.. thanks again.. God bless you all and stackoverflow..you guys have made this world a better place..I almost gave up last night...and thank you again for showing the light again.. thank u very much..

Comment: @LindaMay If my answer is helps to you please accept my answer. :)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply..I  didn't notice the "tick answer"...Ok..I already ticked on the accepted  answer.. tq so much Chinu and to all PHP Masters....

Comment: Ok no problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

> the form keeps submitting data into the DB even when data is wrong or the field is empty

You are checking `$formValid` in the wrong place. Your conditions can be summarized as follows:

```
$formValid = true;
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {

} else if ($formValid) {

} else { ...
```

As above, if `$_POST['register']` is not set (e.g. when loading the registration form) your code will execute whatever is in the second if statement. Your condition structure should be amended to include the form validity check inside the first condition:

```
$formValid = true;
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    // validation stuff goes here
    if ($formValid) {
        //database insert goes here
    }
    else {
        //invalid data. Tell the user
    }
}
```

Also as a rule, you should assume any data from the user is invalid unless proven otherwise i.e. `$formValid` should be `false` initially.

> Notice: Undefined variable: stmt in C:\xampp\htdocs\eventsite\TMP1kjqc3x.php on line 19
>   Fatal error: Call to a member function bindValue() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\eventsite\TMP1kjqc3x.php on line 194

You are trying to use a variable `$stmt` that has not been defined within the scope of `else if($formValid)`. The same goes for `$sql`. Any variable must be set before it is used. The order should be:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, telno, username, password) VALUES (:name, :telno, :username, :password)";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql); 

$stmt->bindValue(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindValue(':telno', $telno);
$stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
$stmt->bindValue(':password', $passwordHash);
```

Comment: Yeah. I thought it would be enough to point this out alone but it isn't. There was a lot to cover in this one.

Comment: wowww....thank you so much ...to all of you.. I never expected a very quick response....woww again...ok ok ..guys...give me some time to go through everything.. because I need to read all your answers and guidance slowly.. I'm a bit slow on this..I apologize...thank you again for the responses...I will update once I manage to get it running.. coz it's bedtime already here in Borneo.. it's quite late already.. I'll continue tomorrow morning.. tqs again